# .htaccess Error, While modifying php configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess

If this is not posted in correct place, please migrate it

I kept a .htaccess file in my `public_html` folder inside the root. When I view the website it is giving server misconfiguration error.

my .htaccess file contains this only

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

I wonder what may be wrong. Any Ideas

**MY ERROR LOG**

```
[Mon Jun 07 17:06:23 2010] [alert] [client 113.199.221.198] /home/wwwcomr/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Mon Jun 07 17:04:46 2010] [alert] [client 113.199.221.198] /home/wwwcomr/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: if possible look in your web server log like suggested. You can also ommit one of the lines to see if a specific one is causing the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess produces 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523135/htaccess-produces-500-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Col. Shrapnel says: The error log is the only place to get reliable information.

Re your update:

PHP needs to be running as an Apache module for `php_value` to work. [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: @Starx yup, you can use `php_value` only when PHP is running as an Apache module. http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: @Starx you'd have to set the values in `php.ini` itself, or re-install PHP as a Apache module. The latter would be a question for serverfault.com - if you can, just change it in php.ini.

Comment: @pekka, I dont have authorization to modify my php.ini

Comment: @Starx then I'm afraid what you are trying to do is not possible I think! You can't use `ini_set` for these specific values, as they need to be set outside the script.

Answer (score 1):

See web-server's error_log for the details.