# .htaccess produces 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache

The content of .htaccess is:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
```

Works on localhost, screws up every hosting server I upload it to.
The error.log says: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Is there another way to change the upload_max_filesize?

Comment: You should read the error logs for more information.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, forgot about that. The error.log says Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: @A-OK: Assuming PHP is running, create a phpinfo() file, and check the server method. `php_value` will only work if `mod_php` is being used, ie. PHP is an Apache Module, if it's FCGI, it will not work.

Comment: Do you use PHP as a module? No for example with FastCGI?

Comment: It's CGI, not even FastCGI :)

Comment: @A-OK: Well there you go, you'll have to get the host to change the setting server-wide if you need it higher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess Error, While modifying php configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988962/htaccess-error-while-modifying-php-configuration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the hosting provider, they only allow changing this via php.ini

Answer (score 15):

If `php_value` is not recognized as a valid command, it may be because PHP is not installed as an Apache module. Create a php file with the following contents:

`<?php phpinfo();`

Run the file to show your PHP configuration.  Search the page (Ctr+F) for "mod_php".  If you don't find it anywhere, this explains your problem.

If you have access to `php.ini`, you may be able to fix your problem by editing that file instead.  At the `phpinfo` page, look at the value under `Loaded Configuration File` for the location of the file to edit. On Linux, it will be something such as `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Open the `ini` file (it's just a text file) and look for the setting you want to change.  If it's not present, just add a line and set it as desired: `upload_max_filesize=64M`

Save the file and restart the Apache server.

Comment: If PHP is not installed in apache, how would `<?php phpinfo();` work?

Comment: I'm getting the error but `php_value` isn't in the `.htaccess` file... I can edit the .ini file but I have no idea what to do there.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to remove the `php_flag` command in `.htaccess` but want to avoid the error, wrap the command as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors 0
    php_flag display_startup_errors 0
</IfModule>
```

If you're using PHP7, use `<IfModule mod_php7.c>`

Answer (score 9):

For other readers with the same problem and access to the server, this could also be caused by a misconfiguration of PHP as a module of apache. You can fix it reinstalling the module (or configuring the route to `libphp.so` by yourself in `php.ini`).

**Have in mind that *purge* will remove the configuration of the packages which usually is nothing to worry, but you are warned just in case.**

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Comment: This was the issue for me. Don't forget to restart apache after this.

Comment: It was a conflict after upgrading to php 7.4 in my case. You proposed solution worked, thank you man.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php 

 —
This helped. 
(Also it's needed restart apach2...)
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the php module is not loaded. Make sure, it is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

and check if it is enabled in apache with

```
ll /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*php*
```

if it is installed but not enabled, enable it (depending on your php-version) e.g. for PHP 8.0 with

```
sudo a2enmod php8.0.load
```

and restart apache

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Answer (score 2):

I too was receiving a 500 internal server error. My error log showed:
Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I tried updating upload_max_filesize as suggested but it didn't work for me. The last line of my .htaccess file had:

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

I removed that line and the site resolved perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create **.user.ini** file
2. Add the line **upload_max_filesize="5M"**