# How to ignore php settings in .htaccess with FastCGI

Tags: php, apache

I try to use php_value in .htaccess, but get internal server error. I saw this article has answer: [500 Internal Server Error when using .htaccess for PHP Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928328)
This is because php_value cannot work with FastCgi.

But I want to ignore the php_value settings with if statement, like
`<IfModule XXX>
some code
</IfModule>.`

My situation is:
I have a shared server, which I don't have permission to edit php.ini, so I need to use the php_value in .htaccess, and it works. But my local pc, I use php-cgi.exe, I have multi php version, 5.4, 5.6, 7.1.

So, is there a way to do like this:

```
<if not fastcgi >
php_value xxx
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP > 5.3, you can use a `.user.ini` file, which overrides `php.ini` on a per-directory basis. Give it a try. Just add a `.user.ini` file to the root directory, and add the php configuration options you need to modify right there.

Read all about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: The php_values in .htaccess need to exist. Because the projects are not only in my local pc, but also in remote shared host. I can change my pc's settings, but I cannot change the shared host. Maybe the only way is to use different .htaccess? I wish to use the same one, on my pc, ignore the php_values, on shared host, work fine.