# Plesk gives 500 error when using the flags httonly and secure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, plesk

Plesk gives a 500 error when using the folowing code in the htacces file:

```
#Dit zorgt ervoor dat .php niet in de url hoeft te staan. 
Schakel mod_rewrite in
RewriteEngine On

#Doorverwijzen naar inloggen.php
RewriteRule ^login$ inloggen.php [L]

#Voeg .php toe aan bestandsnamen
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#cookies
php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
```

What's wrong in the file? Because, when I remove the cookie rules, the htaccess file just works

I tried to use multiple answers on Stackoverflow to try to fix such as plesk configuration but it didn't help.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. However, your Apache may not allow php_value settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928328/500-internal-server-error-when-using-htaccess-for-php-settings

Comment: As written, the second line would also result in a 500 error. `Schakel` is not a valid directive. (You are missing a `#` comment marker)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the php_value lines, it's the "Schakel" line. As MrWhite pointed out, this needs to a comment, else it is interpreted as a directive, and that will fail, because such a directive does not exist.