# php.ini auto_prepend_file not affecting child directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I've always placed

```
php_value auto_prepend_file [path to config.php]
```

in the .htaccess file to include my config.php file in every page. However, I just switched to a new host (namecheap), and this host gives me the error "Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration".

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686596/3866833) answer, the host is forcing me to set the auto_prepend file directly in the php.ini. I did this (placed a php.ini into public_html and set the auto_prepend_file value), and it worked, but only for the home page. In every page besides the home page, the config.php is not included. It seems like the auto prepend only works on every page if I paste the php.ini into every directory, which definitely isn't proper. I'm at a loss how to include the config.php into every php file... I really don't want to paste a require_once command into every file.

Comment: Your php.ini should be in the directory above public_html if you want it to act globally.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but no pages prepend the config.php when I place the php.ini into the root... My tests keep showing that every page gets an error unless I place the php.ini in the same directory as the index

Comment: @l'L'l please re-read the question... my host is forbidding me from setting php values in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/recursive-php-ini).

I had to add `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html` to make the php.ini file recursive instead of setting `php_value`.